# How to use functions in globals variables in ejs/express?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

```
var app = express();
app.locals.current_time = utils.current_time();
```

Can I change variable current_time for each request in template for this variable ? app.locals.current_time in this example is constant, but I want to use function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
app.locals.current_time = function () {
  return utils.current_time();
};
```

then on the ejs template use it like this:

```
<%= current_time() %>
```

Comment: in ejs result : text("function()")

Comment: Are you calling it like <%= current_time() %> ?